# Adding an email to latex file

Tags: untagged

Is it possible to add an email just below the authors in this code also is it possible to make the output come as a two column paper.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\title{Hello}
\author{User1 \and User2}



\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
A1
\section{Literature Review}
A2

\section{Conclusion}
A2

\end{document}
```